# TF_IDF calculation sending errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tf-idf

I am currently working on a small project and have hit a complete mind blank, i have the following code to calculate term frequency:
    from Bag import *

```
words = 
['the','new','the','shiny','new','car','went','through','the','tunnel']
carDoc = Bag()
for word in words:
    carDoc.add(word)

def tf(word, carDoc):
    if word != "" and carDoc.size() > 0:
        return carDoc.count(word)/carDoc.size()
```

I also have the following code for inverse document frequency:

```
from Bag import *
from math import log

carDoc1 = Bag()
for word in ['the', 'car']:
    carDoc1.add(word)

carDoc2 = Bag()
for word in ['the', 'shiny', 'new']:
    carDoc2.add(word)

allCarDocs = [carDoc1, carDoc2]

def idf(word, carDocs):
    total = len(allCarDocs)
    wordIsIn = 0
    for docs in allCarDocs:
        if docs.contains(word):
            wordIsIn = wordIsIn + 1
    return log(total / (1 + wordIsIn))

carDoc1 = Bag()
for word in ['the', 'car']:
    carDoc1.add(word)
carDoc2 = Bag()
for word in ['the', 'shiny', 'new']:
    carDoc2.add(word)

allCarDocs = [carDoc1, carDoc2]

def tf_idf(word, documents):
    return tf(word, carDoc) * idf (word, allCarDocs)
```

and the error i get is carDoc not defined

These are fine and work as i intended them too, but when it comes to implementing the tfidf function i keep getting errors. Any help in resolving the tfidf for this example will be appreciated

Comment: Can you also post the error?

Answer (score 0):

def tf_idf(word, documents):
    return tf(word, carDoc) * idf (word, allCarDocs)

where do you want to get carDoc and allCarDocs if your function take (word, **documents**)??